# How to use HR2Day to fetch only the employee resource

Tags: salesforce

I'm trying to use the REST API from salesforce to get the resource employee HR2Day.

However, I get all entities when I do a call. Also, I cannot make a specific call like `/emplyees` or on id.

In the documentation it talks about that hr2day has rest API but in contrast it works query based.

Comment: I've never used the Salesforce API. Looking to HR2Days info, they do mention `query based` or `rest` API, and had a link to the [rest API here](https://hr2day-6087.force.com/hr2daydeveloper/s/rest-api?tabset-3b57b=e3919). Perhaps the `Resources` section of the page might help?

Comment: @PaulT. Thanks for you reply, is still very unclear, 
because it doesn't look like rest api